# What would the Mercator projection look like if the north pole were in a different spot like in Hapgood's Planet?

Tags: geography, geology, map-making

This scenario is based on the out-of-date Earth crust displacement theory of Charles Hapgood. Before the theory of plate tectonics was accepted, he said that the poles physically moved over millions of years. He used the following as examples of past north poles:

- Yukon
- Hudson Bay
- The body of water between Iceland and Scandinavia

But regardless of Hapgood's fallibility on crust displacement, what would the Mercator projection look like if the north pole were in any of those three listed spots?

Comment: Enjoy : http://mrgris.com/projects/merc-extreme/#64.06007,-139.43203

Comment: Related: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/18869/what-would-the-map-look-like-if-the-north-pole-moved-to-tibet.

Comment: If you want to change how this site works then please suggest it in [meta](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Wouldn't is just be a matter of moving things on the projection?  I guess I am not sure what the world-building relevance is.

Comment: @James I tried with several software used to convert map projections and they could not change the latitude of the pole. Maybe it's because Mercator cannot map the poles in the first place. Therefore, I'm not sure that what i posted is a Mercator projection or something that looks like it.

Comment: @Vincent That site froze my computer due to heavy swapping :(

Answer (score 1):

There are some tools available to calculate Mercator projection. For example, for matlab, you can look at [this](https://de.mathworks.com/help/map/projection-aspect.html) library. Which explains how to make a map projection, and how to set the origin of the projection. I haven't tried myself, but it looks quite promising to get any information.